# Laravel: Null and Empty

Tags: laravel

1. At least one character, not one space, two spaces, not null.
2. Null or only spaces

1- At least one character, not one space, two spaces, not null.
In MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE invoice_code IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(invoice_code)<>''
```

How to do this in Eloquent?

```
$query->whereNotNull('invoice_code');
$query->whereNotEmpty('invoice_code');
```

This will fail.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'not_empty' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` where `not_empty` = invoice_code
```

whereNotEmpty becomes `not_empty`

2- Null or only spaces

```
SELECT * FROM cart_orders 
WHERE invoice_code IS NULL or TRIM(invoice_code)=''
```

If I use whereRaw(), it's bad for sql injection issue, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple where for the empty check:

```
$query->where('invoice_code', '!=', '')
```

But you still have to use the null check if you want to check for NULL values.

And to answer you other question, yes using `whereRaw` is a big SQL Injection issue since it doesn't escape the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using null for empty values Model::whereNotNull('invoice_code');

If you are using an empty string Model::where('invoice_code' '<>', '');